# Java Printer Service throws ClassCastException while using PrinterURI Attribute

Tags: java

I have implemented a program, to print the document to the specific printer using IP address, printer name

Code:

```
URI myURI=null;
FileInputStream psStream=null;
try   {
       psStream = new FileInputStream( "sample.docx" );
   }
catch ( FileNotFoundException e )   {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF;
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc( psStream, psInFormat, null );
     PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    aset.add( new Copies(5) );
    try {             
        String host="192.255.301.147";
        String printer="HP LaserJet 5000 Series PCL6";
        String theUrl = "ipp://"+host+"/printers/"+printer;
        theUrl = URLEncoder.encode(theUrl, "UTF-8");
        myURI =  new URI(theUrl);       
              aset.add(new PrinterURI(myURI));  
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("URI exception caught: "+e);         
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
    }

  PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( psInFormat, aset );
   if ( services.length > 0 ) {
     DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob();          
     try {
             job.print( myDoc, aset );
     }
     catch ( PrintException e ){
     }
}
```

While running the program, got **ClasscastException**.

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException
    at javax.print.attribute.AttributeSetUtilities.verifyAttributeValue(AttributeSetUtilities.java:534)
    at javax.print.attribute.HashAttributeSet.add(HashAttributeSet.java:283)
    at com.src.print.TestPrint2.main(TestPrint2.java:64)
```

With out adding PrinterURI Attribute in the RequestAttributeSet (***aset.add(new PrinterURI(myURI))***), the Program is working fine. 
Its taking default printer configuration and printing the document.

Could you please help me out on this. how to use PrinterURI API?

Comment: Your exception and your code doesn't match. What's on line 64 in `TestPrint2.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the stacktrace and related class documentation, this exception most likely occurs because [HashPrintRequestAttributeSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/HashPrintRequestAttributeSet.html) (which extends [PrintRequestAttributeset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttributeSet.html)) enforces that all added type must conforms to [PrintRequestAttribute](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttribute.html).

If you see the documentation of [PrinterURI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterURI.html), you would see that it does not implement that interface that cause the exception. Reading your code and question, I would guess you might want to use [Destination](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/Destination.html) instead of PrinterURI.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same error message "ClasscastException". I found it myself it is a careless mistake. Hope to help others.

```
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( psInFormat, aset );
```

.lookupPrintServices is using ***PrintServiceAttributeSet***

```
job.print( myDoc, aset );
```

.print is using ***PrintRequestAttributeSet***

They are not same set of AttributeSet